# Bootstrap Popover inside of a link in a table cell does not display

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-popover

I have a link within a table cell that on the hover action, I would like a Bootstrap Popover to appear.  As of now, I cannot get this to work correctly.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<table style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
 <tr style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0;">
  <td style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0; text-align:left; width:100px">
   <a href="#" id="lastBACommentCell" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-template="<div class='mainViewPopover' role='tooltip'><div class='arrow'></div><div class='popover-content' style='color: #FFFFFF;'></div></div>" data-content="Here is my popover">
    Hover here for the popover to appear...
   </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
...
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#lastBACommentCell').popover();
     });
    </script>
```

I have tried putting a `<span>` inside the `<a>` tag, but it still will not display the popover.

Here is the JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dzeller44/swnbdjaq/

Comment: would help if your fiddle included the libraries....

Comment: My apologies - just added the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I've included bootstrap and JQuery to the jsfiddle, The popover itself works, the problem is that you don't see it (because it is not styled) I've added a dummy text to see that the popover works -
 https://jsfiddle.net/km7pn81z/9/. You could also remove the `data-template` to see that it works.

Just add this CSS to make it more visible:

```
.mainViewPopover{
  background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated your code and it works for me without the data content.
I included bootstrap css library, jQuery and bootstrap js library (imp for popover to work).

Here is the link:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLJrzJ

code:
 HTML

```
        <table style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
     <tr style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0;">
      <td style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0; text-align:left; width:100px">
       <a href="#" id="lastBACommentCell" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover"  data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Here is my popover">
        Hover here for the popover to appear...
       </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

JS

`$(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
     });`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `data-template` syntax. The outermost wrapper element should have the .popover class. You are also using `style='color: #FFFFFF` on an element with a white background.

> [**Bootstrap Popover Options**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options)
>
> *...The outermost wrapper element should have the .popover class.*

So in the `data-template` attribute change this:

```
<div class='mainViewPopover' role='tooltip'>
  <div class='arrow'></div>
  <div class='popover-content' style='color: #FFFFFF;'></div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class='mainViewPopover popover' role='tooltip'>
  <div class='arrow'></div>
  <div class='popover-content'></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lastBACommentCell').popover()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0;">
    <td style="background: transparent; border: 0; outline: 0; text-align:left; width:100px">
      <a href="#" id="lastBACommentCell" 
        tabindex="0" 
        data-toggle="popover" 
        role="button" 
        data-trigger="hover" 
        data-placement="bottom" 
        data-content="Here is my popover" 
        data-template="<div class='mainViewPopover popover' role='tooltip'><div class='arrow'></div><div class='popover-content'></div></div>" >
        Hover here for the popover to appear...
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```